# Регулярное выражение (только буквы или только буквы и цифры, или только буквы, цифры и спецсимволы +_@-. нельзя только спецсимволы и только цифры)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9+_@-.]$/
```

1. можно буквы лат. алфавита в любом регистре
2. можно буквы лат. алфавита в любом регистре и цифры
3. можно либо буквы в любом регистре и цифры и символы `+_@-.`
4. нельзя только символы `+_@-.`
5. нельзя только цифры
6. нельзя только символы `+_@-.` вместе с цифрами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
/^(?![\d+_@.-]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9+_@.-]*$/
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/LpMBtr/2).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?![\d+_@.-]+$)` - отрицающий блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции в строке есть только один или более символов `_`, `@`, `.`, `-` или цифр
- `[a-zA-Z0-9+_@.-]*` - ноль и более букв, цифр или знаков `+`, `_`, `@`, `.` и `-`
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: плохо разбираюсь в регулярках, благодарю за объяснение